# Re-render the component if some of multiple checkboxes is checked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

-Hello, I made a code to **send props** value from **child component to parent component**

in the child component I have multiple checkboxes with a value that I'll pass to the props, in addition of two functions, the first function to store the clicked inputs on array and pass it to the props and the second function to call the first function if the user check new input (this function used to update the props value )

```
export const ColorsForm = (props) => {

   useEffect(()=>{
      test()
   },[])

   // this function to store the checked colors in array then pass this array to the props
   const getColors = () => {
       const inpColor = document.querySelectorAll(".colorsInp");
       let arrOfColors = [];
       for(let i = 0; i < inpColor.length; i++){
           if(inpColor[i].checked){
               arrOfColors.push(inpColor[i].value);
           }
       }
       props.array_of_colors(arrOfColors);
       return arrOfColors;
   }

   // this function will be used to resend the prop value with new value
   const whenNewColorClicked = () => {
       const inpColor = document.querySelectorAll(".colorsInp");
       for(let i = 0; i < inpColor.length; i++){
           inpColor[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
              getColors();
           })
       }
   }

   return (
       <div>
           <label>Colors:</label>
           <div>
               <input type="checkbox" id="colorBlack" value="black" name='colorsInput' />
               <label htmlFor="colorBlack" className='lblBlack'></label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="colorWhite" value="white" name='colorsInput' />
               <label htmlFor="colorWhite" className='lblWhite'></label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="colorRed" value="red" name='colorsInput' />
               <label htmlFor="colorRed" className='lblRed'></label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="colorBlue" value="blue" name='colorsInput'/>
               <label htmlFor="colorBlue" className='lblBlue'></label>
           </div>
      </div>
   )
}
```

**the parent component** is where I'll valid the upcoming props to make a post request

```
import React, { useState ,useEffect } from 'react'  
import { ColorsForm } from './colorsForm';

export const AddForm = () => {
    const [colors, setColors] = useState([])

    return (
        <>
        <ColorsForm array_of_colors={res => setColors(() => [...res])} />
        <button onClick={postRequestFunction} >Insert</button>
        </>          
    );
}
```

my code works fine but...
I know the child component code can be wrote better than I did, please feel free to notice anything, I'll be thankful

Answer (score 0):

You do an "anti-pattern" here.

The parent **must have the information** and the children **must display and interact with this information**.

So the `colors` array must be define in the parent and your `ColorsForm` must `.map` the `colors` array props to display the different color in the form with the correct value.

Then, if you use `document.querySelector` is that there is a problem.
React manages the DOM and you should never do it for it. In your two functions, you should never listen to the click event by hand.

So I can't explain everything here, but I hope this information will help you improve your code. The best way to learn is to search and find answers by yourself